# Export from database to .CSV

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

With the help of PHPExcel plugin I created this PHP script to export some data from a database to a .CSV document.

The problem is that the data on the .CSV document stays all in the same column after the export, only separated by commas.

It works as expected if I export to .XLS instead of .CSV.

It is possible to export to .CSV and keep the format that I want instead of separate by commas?

```
<?php
                session_start();
                error_reporting(0);
                ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
                ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
                set_time_limit (120);

                $db=mysqli_connect('','','','testes') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($db));
                mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');
                $time=$_SESSION['id_ficheiro'];

                $SQL1="select data from testes.lidl_promos where id_ficheiro='$time' group by data";
                $result1=mysqli_query($db, $SQL1);
                while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                $data_promo=$row1['data'];

                $SQL="select loja, date_format(data_entrega,'%d%m%Y') as data_ent,artigo,caixas from testes.lidl_promos where data='$data_promo' and id_ficheiro='$time'";
                $result=mysqli_query($db, $SQL);

                ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../plugin/phpexcel/');
                require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
                require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

                $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
                $r=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

                $r->setCellValue('A1', 'Lojas');
                $rowcount=2;

                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){               

                        $r->setCellValue('A'.$rowcount, $row['loja']);
                        $r->setCellValue('C'.$rowcount, $row["data_ent"]);
                        $r->setCellValue('D1', $row['artigo']);
                        $r->setCellValue('D'.$rowcount, $row['caixas']);
                        ++$rowcount;
                }


                header("Content-type: text/csv");

                //header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="report.xls"');
                $date=date('dmY');
                $new_data_promo = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data_promo));
                $name=$date.'_promo_'.$new_data_promo;
                //$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
                $objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,'lidl_output/'.$name.'.csv',__FILE__));
                //$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
                //$objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,'lidl_output/'.$name.'.xls',__FILE__));

                }
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Exportado com sucesso'));

                die();
                exit;

?>
```

Comment: CSV stands for "comma separated values." Your question is confusing, please clarify.

Comment: php has built in csv functions, i don't know why your using PHPexcel here

Comment: I'd not use PHPExcel for this, I'd simply use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function; but you need to be very careful opening CSV files in MS Excel, because the separator is specific to the locale of the version of MS Excel, and the wrong separator simply won't be recognised

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to format the code on the comments.

$handle = false;
  $rowcount=1;
  $date=date('dmY');
  $new_data_promo = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data_promo));
  $name=$date.'_promo_'.$new_data_promo;
  $handle = fopen("lidl_output/".$name.".csv", 'a+');
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

   if($rowcount==1){
    if($handle){ 
     fwrite($handle, "Lojas","","",$row['artigo']);
    }
   }
   else{
    if($handle){
     fwrite($handle, $row['loja'],"",$row['data_ent'],$row['caixas']);
    }
   }   

   
   ++$rowcount;
   fputcsv($handle, $row);
  }
  
  fclose($handle);

Comment: Still doesn't work. Same problem.

Comment: So try changing the separator to a `;`.... like I said before, MS Excel expects different separators depending on the locale settings of MS Excel itself

Comment: It's working with a ; @Mark Baker.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Just note that if you send that file to others, they may have different locale settings in their MS Excel.... that's one big drawback with MS Excel's ability to import CSV files